# Where to write code of embed viewcontroller in containerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicontainerview

I am working on a project which contains 3 container view with 3 child viewcontrollers. I am new at container view So I want to know where to write code of that child view controllers. I load that viewcontrollers with adding child viewcontrollers in containerview with use of seague. 
[image]

As per I googled, There are demos like they only load viewcontrollers in containerview with just changing background color.

I want to know that If I have to make different classes for that view controllers that embed in containerviews?

Thank you for your help

Comment: were you able to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to create UIViewController class for each embedded View Controller.

Doing this will give you control over the embedded View Controllers like normal View Controller do.

Comment: Ok, I will try it Thanks